# Stored Procedure libraries

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Let's say I have a Data Access class library containing thousands of methods, with each one calling a stored procedure in a SQL Server database. The methods are organized in about a hundred separate classes. Is there a way to create collapsible libraries or something to that effect instead of having one gigantic listing of stored procedures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you're asking about the list of procedures that appears in the UI of SQL Server Management Studio, I don't think there's a way to do that by default. One workaround that you might consider would be to group your stored procedures into different schemas, perhaps matching your classes in your data access layer, and then use the filtering in SSMS to only show the schema that you're interested in seeing at that time.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I know it seems like a minor thing, except it really does make it harder, or at least significantly more time consuming, to logically group and search through SPs when you use them extensively to enforce minimum database privileges.